# IF condition not working in Java Selenium

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

What is wrong with the `if`-condition below? When both strings have same value, it is not going inside `if`-condition.

```
for(int j=0; j<types; j++){
    List<WebElement> category = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='pure-menu-selected']"));
    for(int k=0; k<category.size(); k++){
        String matchtype_from_excel = tours.getRow(x).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().toUpperCase().trim();
        String matchtype_from_entry = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='pure-menu-selected']["+k+"+1]/a")).getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        if(matchtype_from_excel.equals(matchtype_from_entry)){
            category.get(k+1).click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how, but it is working. Match_type_excel i am getting from excel sheet. In the excel itself entered as capital letters. In the code I used touppercase method. Still did not work. But having capital letters in excel is working fine...